# No match to overload variants

Tags: python, dependency-injection, overload-resolution

I have an issue with the iservice package I created few weeks ago (a dependency injection engine) [source here](https://lab.frogg.it/dorianturba/iservice). Mypy complains about the signature not matching any overload variant, but I don't get why:

```py
# mypy_test.py
import typing
from iservice import inject, Service
from constants import Database
import implem


class ISettings(Service, typing.Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def database() -> Database:
        """
        load database settings
        """


def database_setting(settings: type[ISettings]) -> Database:
    return settings.database()


super_settings = inject(database_setting, implem)
```

```py
# constants.py
class Database:
    poc_url: str
```

```py
# implem.py
from constant import Database


def database() -> Database:
    return Database()
```

Mypy error:

```
mypy_test.py:31: error: No overload variant of "inject" matches argument types "Callable[[Type[ISettings]], Database]", Module  [call-overload]
mypy_test.py:31: note: Possible overload variants:
mypy_test.py:31: note:     def [S1 <: Service, P`-2, R] inject(Callable[[Type[S1], **P], R], Type[S1], /) -> Callable[P, R]
mypy_test.py:31: note:     def [S1 <: Service, S2 <: Service, P`-3, R] inject(Callable[[Type[S1], Type[S2], **P], R], Type[S1], Type[S2], /) -> Callable[P, R]
mypy_test.py:31: note:     def [S1 <: Service, S2 <: Service, S3 <: Service, P`-4, R] inject(Callable[[Type[S1], Type[S2], Type[S3], **P], R], Type[S1], Type[S2], Type[S3], /) -> Callable[P, R]
mypy_test.py:31: note:     def [S1 <: Service, S2 <: Service, S3 <: Service, S4 <: Service, P`-5, R] inject(Callable[[Type[S1], Type[S2], Type[S3], Type[S4], **P], R], Type[S1], Type[S2], Type[S3], Type[S4], /) -> Callable[P, R]
```

Here is the implementation of inject: https://lab.frogg.it/dorianturba/iservice/-/blob/main/src/iservice/inject.py

When I look at the signature `Callable[[Type[ISettings]], Database]`, it seems to match the `Callable[[Type[S1], **P], R]`